# How do you remove a RigidArea from a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

To add a RigidArea, say, to put space between components, you do:

```
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(int, int))):
```

In general, how would you remove that space from said panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would you remove that space from said panel?

The rigid area is a component just like a button or text field. So keep a reference to it:

```
Component emptySpace = Box.createRigidArea( ... );
panel.add( emptySpace );
```

Then when you want to remove it you would use:

```
panel.remove( emptySpace );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```